SimPy: Strange transient level attribute values of Container resource
I am experimenting with SimPy and I try to monitor the level of a Container resource.
For illustration purposes, please consider the simple example of a producer process that produces an item every 3 time steps. and puts them into the container, and a consumer process that takes a single item from the container at every time step. The initial container level is 3.
I implemented this as follows:
import simpy

# define a "producer" that puts a new item in the container every 3 time units
def producer(env, container):
    while(True):
        yield env.timeout(3)
        print(f'Producer at t = {env.now}: Produced item. '
              f'Requesting to put it into container. '
              f'Current container level (before putting): {container.level}')
        yield container.put(1)
        print(f'Producer at t = {env.now}: Successfully put produced item into container. '
              f'New container level: {container.level}')

# define a "consumer" that attempts to take one item from the container at every time unit
def consumer(env, container):
    while(True):
        print(f'Consumer at t = {env.now}: Requesting item from container. '
              f'Current container level (before taking item): {container.level}')
        yield container.get(1)
        print(f'Consumer at t = {env.now}: Consumed item from container. '
              f'New container level: {container.level}')
        yield env.timeout(2)

# setup the simpy environment
env = simpy.Environment()
container = simpy.Container(env, init = 3)
producer_process = env.process(producer(env, container))
consumer_process = env.process(consumer(env, container))

# run the simulation
print(f'Initial container level: {container.level}')
env.run(until=7)

This results in the following output:
Initial container level: 3
Consumer at t = 0: Requesting item from container. Current container level (before taking item): 3
Consumer at t = 0: Consumed item from container. New container level: 2
Consumer at t = 2: Requesting item from container. Current container level (before taking item): 2
Consumer at t = 2: Consumed item from container. New container level: 1
Producer at t = 3: Produced item. Requesting to put it into container. Current container level (before putting): 1
Producer at t = 3: Successfully put produced item into container. New container level: 2
Consumer at t = 4: Requesting item from container. Current container level (before taking item): 2
Consumer at t = 4: Consumed item from container. New container level: 1
Producer at t = 6: Produced item. Requesting to put it into container. Current container level (before putting): 1
Consumer at t = 6: Requesting item from container. Current container level (before taking item): 2
Producer at t = 6: Successfully put produced item into container. New container level: 1
Consumer at t = 6: Consumed item from container. New container level: 1

I think this result is strange. For example, according to the output, the container level at time 6 increases from 1 to 2 even before the newly produced item is placed in the container.
My question is: How and when is the container level attribute updated in simpy and how can I obtain or create a correct log of all transient level changes?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@СергейКох Thank you, I now limited my question to the first of two issues I have regarding the monitoring of container levels in simpy.  I hope this will now be easier to get help with.

keep in mind every time a procedure does a yield, it gives up control of the thread allowing another procedure to run.  Eventually, the yielding procedure will resume and finish.
so when the producer starts, it prints, then does it put and yield.
This allows the Comsumer to start and print, then get and yield.
Then the producer starts back up and does its final print, and ends
and the consumer starts back up and finishes.
Also do not count on there being any order of what runs next.  Plan on the order of what can run at time x to be random.
The point is your procedures may not run from start to finish, it can take a break at a yield and during that break another procedure can run.
